# Formatting Standard Post Format

Tags: post-formats, css

I'm looking to display an image for all the "standard" post formats on my site. I have done some research on how to add quote, video, photo, etc and have been able to implement these images into the site but when it comes to the "standard" post type I get nothing!

I have done all the necessary steps in the functions.php file:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'chat', 'gallery', 'image', 'link', 'quote', 'status', 'video', 'audio' ) );
```

And my code to display the images is as follows:

```
<div class="post-format">

<?php if(has_post_format('video')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post-icons/video.png" alt="Video" />
    <?php } ?>

<?php if(has_post_format('image')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post-icons/photo.png" alt="Photo" />
    <?php } ?>

<?php if(has_post_format('standard')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post-icons/text.png" alt="Text" />
    <?php } ?>

<?php if(has_post_format('audio')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post-icons/audio.png" alt="audio" />
    <?php } ?>

<?php if(has_post_format('aside')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post-icons/aside.png" alt="aside" />
    <?php } ?>

<?php if(has_post_format('gallery')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post-icons/gallery.png" alt="gallery" />
    <?php } ?>

<?php if(has_post_format('link')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post-icons/link.png" alt="link" />
    <?php } ?>

<?php if(has_post_format('quote')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post-icons/quote.png" alt="quote" />
    <?php } ?>

<?php if(has_post_format('status')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post-icons/status.png" alt="status" />
    <?php } ?>

<?php if(has_post_format('false')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post-icons/standard.png" alt="standard" />
    <?php } ?>

<?php if(has_post_format('chat')) { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post-icons/chat.png" alt="chat" />
    <?php } ?>
```

Can anyone help me out on how to get the standard post images to display?

Answer (score 5):

Technically speaking, there is no "standard" Post Format. Rather, "standard" is simply the *default* - as in, no Post Format type is defined.

If no Post Format type is defined, `get_post_format()` simply returns `null`.

I would suggest re-factoring your code above, and re-naming your icon images using the exact Post Format string. That way, you could do:

```
<div class="post-format">

<?php $format = get_post_format(); ?>

<?php if( $format ) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/post-icons/<?php echo $format; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $format; ?>" />
<?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/post-icons/standard.png" alt="Standard" />
<?php } ?>

</div>
```

Or perhaps:

```
<div class="post-format">

    <?php $format = ( get_post_format() ? get_post_format() : 'standard' ); ?>

    <img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/post-icons/<?php echo $format; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $format; ?>" />

</div>
```

Either one should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code instead of your block:

```
<?php 
$format = get_post_format();
if ( false === $format ) {
?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/post-icons/standard.png" alt="standard" />
<?php 
}
?>
```